Re entering Singapore after deportation for cannabis
It's been 6 years now since I was deported by Singapore to Malaysia because I tested positive for cannabis on my way for an interview at Singapore immigration.
What should I do to be able to work in Singapore?

There are more or less 190 other countries. While I understand Singapore is the richest country close to you, you should probably set your sights on others (though many will ask questions which will require you to tell them about that deportation).

Was it a random drug test, or part of the interview process at Singapore immigration?

It was a random drug test took place while I'm on my way to attend an interview at singapore.happened on 2018.

Straight away been deported back to malaysia.never been experience working there before

Unfortunately it is unlikely that you will be allowed to work in Singapore. Singapore Legal Advice:

Even if you are not dismissed by your employer, your criminal conviction may make it difficult to renew your work pass when it is about to expire.


You may also be placed on a “blacklist” (i.e. a list of foreigners who are banned from obtaining employment in Singapore because of a criminal conviction), which could affect your future employment prospects in Singapore and the status of your work pass.


If you are convicted and are deemed by the Immigration and Checkpoint Authority (ICA) to be an undesirable immigrant because of the circumstances connected with your conviction, you and your family may be regarded as prohibited immigrants.

However!

If the offence that you committed was not a serious offence, and if you have a crime-free period of 5 consecutive years from the date that you were sentenced (if you were not sentenced to imprisonment) or the date of your release from prison (if you were imprisoned), your criminal record may become “spent”.

So you can try reaching out to the Singapore Police Force and obtaining a Certificate of Clearance to confirm that your conviction is considered spent. Good luck!

It isn't clear from the question whether OP was convicted of a crime, or simply refused entry.

@NateEldredge Deportations in Singapore are listed on your criminal record, that's why the police clearance cert is needed. But yes, it's unclear what the exact circumstances were.
